# How can I insert an runtime environment variable in an annotation attribute value in Java?

Tags: java, annotations, environment-variables, runtime

I have been trying to populate an annotation attribute value at runtime, but it is not being able to compile
The error is

> "The value for annotation attribute
>   DynamoDBIndexHashKey.globalSecondaryIndexName must be a constant
>   expression"

Here is the snippet

```
public static final String GLOBAL_SECONDARY_INDEX = "RENDITIONS" + System.getenv("REGION_CODE") + "-" +System.getenv("STAGE") + "-renditionStatus-Index";

@DynamoDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexName  = GLOBAL_SECONDARY_INDEX, attributeName ="renditionStatus")
```

The value for GLOBAL_SECONDARY_INDEX for the attribute `globalSecondaryIndexName` is not able to compile as a constant despite of using the "+" operator. Am I missing something?
Many Thanks in advance for trying to help

Comment: This cannot be done. It needs to be a compile-time constant. Even if it worked, the environment variables would be taken during compilation, not during the runtime of the application. You will need to use some other mechanism to configure your application, annotations are resolved at compile-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to dynamically resolve GSI name, although it is pretty hacky.

1. Instead of using `System.getenv("REGION_CODE")` in the expression just use some kind of a template string e.g. `{{env.REGION_CODE}}` or `__REGION_CODE__`, in this example I will use `{{env.REGION_CODE}}`.

```java
public class MyClass {
  @DynamoDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = "RENDITIONS-{{env.REGION_CODE}}-{{env.STAGE}}", attributeName = "renditionStatus")
  private String bar;
}
```

2. create a new method which will process the template, e.g.

```
package com.mycompany.myproduct.utils;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TemplateProcessor {
   public static String processTemplate(String mustacheTemplate) {
       return Arrays.stream(mustacheTemplate.split("\\{\\{|}}"))
               .map(chunk -> chunk.startsWith("env.") ? System.getenv(chunk.substring(4)) : chunk)
               .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
   }
}
```

3. Patch all the codes where `DynamoDBIndexHashKey.globalSecondaryIndexName()` is used.

   i. Find and copy all the classes that use `DynamoDBIndexHashKey.globalSecondaryIndexName()` into your project while making sure that the package part remains the same as the original.

   ii. Everyplace where `globalSecondaryIndexName()` is called wrap it with calling the previously created `processTemplate` method.

Luckily (currently, in com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:1.12.422) the only place that calls `DynamoDBIndexHashKey.globalSecondaryIndexName()` is `StandardAnnotationMaps.FieldMap.globalSecondaryIndexNames()` so the patching won't take too much time.

The end result should look something like this:

```
package com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling;

...
import static com.mycompany.myproduct.utils.TemplateProcessor.processTemplate;
...

final class StandardAnnotationMaps {
  ...
  public Map<KeyType,List<String>> globalSecondaryIndexNames() {
    ...
    String processed = processTemplate(indexHashKey.globalSecondaryIndexName());
    gsis.put(HASH, Collections.singletonList(processed));
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the solution suggested by *balazs*, you can use the Spring Expression Language (SpEL), see

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions,
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-expression-language.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>de.scrum-master</groupId>
  <artifactId>SO_JavaUseSpELWithoutSpring_62301513</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.6</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-jcl</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q62301513;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface DynamoDBIndexHashKey {
  String value();
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q62301513;

import org.springframework.expression.ExpressionParser;
import org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser;

@DynamoDBIndexHashKey("'RENDITIONS-' + get('REGION_CODE') + '-' + get('STAGE') + '-renditionStatus-Index'")
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExpressionParser expressionParser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    String parsedAnnotationValue = expressionParser
      .parseExpression(Main.class.getAnnotation(DynamoDBIndexHashKey.class).value())
      .getValue(System.getenv(), String.class);
    System.out.println(parsedAnnotationValue);
  }
}
```

Now e.g. set environment variables `REGION_CODE=DE` and `STAGE=integration` and run the program. The console log will print:

```
RENDITIONS-DE-integration-renditionStatus-Index
```

SpEL is quite powerful, and you can use it outside of Spring, if you do not mind that `spring-core` is a transitive dependency. But I think, this is acceptable if you make heavy use of it.

---

**Update:** If instead of using the `Map.get` method of the evaluation root object `System.getenv()` in your SpEL expression, you can also use `#root` and use the map accessor syntax `['myKey']`, i.e. instead of

```java
@DynamoDBIndexHashKey("'RENDITIONS-' + get('REGION_CODE') + '-' + get('STAGE') + '-renditionStatus-Index'")
```

you can write

```java
@DynamoDBIndexHashKey("'RENDITIONS-' + #root['REGION_CODE'] + '-' + #root['STAGE'] + '-renditionStatus-Index'")
```

You could also bind the value to a named variable like `env`, if you prefer not to use the root object ex- or implicitly.

Comment: Please note my update with the alternative SpEL syntax `#root['REGION_CODE']`.